# What is the best practice to convert the UI mockup in PSD to master pages and CSS for an ASP.NET MVC site?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, master-pages

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC e-commerce site. I got a UI mockup in PSD from the customer, and need help converting it to master pages, views, CSS, etc. What would be the best approach to this?

Comment: There are professional services that can convert PSD to HTML/CSS, but most of them are geared toward WordPress, Joomla! and other CMS platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't "convert it". You need to look at it as your model for a layout and code your own HTML to match the design. Drop it into Photoshop and start to slice it up into pieces, saving individual images where needed.

The best (and I believe only) approach: **Do it by hand**.